# Finding the minimal and maximal value of complex $|z - a| + |z + a|$ algebraically

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, metric-spaces

This is part of the exercise 4 of Ahlfors: *Show that there exists complex numbers $z$ satisfying $2|c| = |z - a| + |z + a|$ iff $|a| \leq |c|$*. I've managed to show $|z - a| + |z + a| = 2|c| \implies |a| \leq |c|$, but currently I'm stuck at showing the converse. To that end I'm trying to argue about the minimal/maximal value of $|z - a| + |z + a|$ algebraically, if possible. By squaring both sides we get that $4|c|^2 = |z|^2 + |a|^2 + 2|z - a||z + a|$, but beyond this point I'm not sure how to proceed. Specifically, I don't know how to justify an upper/lower bound by writing $2|z - a||z + a|$ as $|z + a||z + a| + |z - a||z - a| = |z + a|^2 + |z - a|^2 = |z|^2 + |a|^2$.

Comment: What does it mean for a complex number to satisfy $| z - a | + | z +a |$? Do you mean $| z -a | \leq | z+a |$?

Comment: @VeryConfused I am pretty sure it should be $|z - a | + |z+a| = 2 |c|$.

Comment: @VeryConfused My bad! Yes, it should be $|z - a| + |z + a| = 2|c|$.

Comment: All the $z$ form an ellipse with $\pm a$ as foci and $\pm a\frac{|c|}{|a|}$ as major axis

Comment: Think about what the quantity $|z+a|+|z-a|$ represents geometrically. That's a lot easier than the algebra.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something for the converse: Taking first $z=a$ yields $|z-a|+|z+a| = 2|a| \leq 2|c|$. Taking now $z=2c+a$ yields $|z-a|+|z+a|\geq 2|c|+2(|c|-|a|) \geq 2|c|$. Hence there must be a $z$ satisfying the equality.