# Finding the minimum and maximum value of $|z|$ satisfying $|z + a| + |z - a| = 2|c|$ for $|a| \leq |c|, a, c, z \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

My problem is essentially the same as this one: [Finding the minimal and maximal value of complex $|z - a| + |z + a|$ algebraically](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4213457/1027258). I do understand that $|z - a| + |z + a| = 2|c|$ represents an ellipse, but I am not sure how to find the upper and lower bounds for $|z|$. I managed to reason about one possible lower bound by: $4|c|^2 = 2(|z|^2 + |a|^2) + 2|z - a||z + a| \leq 2(|z|^2 + |a|^2) + |z - a|^2|z + a|^2 = 4(|z|^2 + |a|^2) \Longleftrightarrow \sqrt{|c|^2 - |a|^2}\leq |z|$, but I am not sure is this the lowest possible bound for $|z|$. As for the upper bound, I really don't have any idea how to begin.

Comment: You say you know it's an ellipse. I suggest you keep thinking geometrically rather than algebraically. Where on the ellipsis is closest to the origin? Where is furthest away?

Comment: I removed the complex-geometry tag since it was not accurate (see its description: "For elementary questions about geometry in the complex plane, use the tags (complex-numbers) and (geometry) instead.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling $A=point(-a),\ B=point(a),\ M=point(z)$ you get $MA+MB=2|c|$

Which identifies clearly as an ellipse (exception when $|c|=|a|$ in which case it is the segment $[AB]$ and min, max are trivial in this case.) centered at the origin whose big axis is along $(AB)$. However since $a$ is complex, the ellipse is most probably rotated.

- Still, the maximum of $|z|$ is when $M$ belongs to the big axis, i.e $(z=at)$ with $t$ real.

You also get $|z-a|+|z+a|=|a|\Big(\underbrace{|t-1|+|t+1|}_{f(t)}\Big)=|2c|$.

Since $|c|>|a|$ we are in the case where $t<-1$ and $f(t)\searrow$ or $t>1$ and $f(t)\nearrow$ so $f$ injective on both intervals and we will get exactly two solutions (one point on $A$ side, and one point on $B$ side) with same modulus (symmetrical to origin)

For sake on simplicity let consider $t>1$ then $f(t)=t-1+t+1=2t=\frac{2|c|}{|a|}$

> Therefore $|z_{max}|=|at|=|c|$.

- It is similar for the minimum case $M$ belongs to the small axis $(z=iat)$ with $t$ real.

*Note: direction vector of $(AB)$ is $a=a_x+ia_y=vec(a_x,a_y)$ is perpendicular to $vec(-a_y,a_x)=-a_y+ia_x=ia$.*

$\begin{align}|z-a|+|z+a|&=|iat-a|+|iat+a|\\&=|a|\Big(|it-1|+|it+1|\Big)\\&=2|a||it+1|=2|c|\end{align}$

$\implies\sqrt{1+t^2}=\frac{|c|}{|a|}$

*Note: $|it-1|=|\overline{it-1}|=|-it-1|=|it+1|$ because $t$ is real*

Again we get exactly two values for symmetrical points, let's concentrate on $t>0$

> $|a|^2+|a|^2t^2=|c|^2\implies |z_{min}|=|iat|=|at|=\sqrt{|c|^2-|a|^2}$

Comment: Should it be that $f\nearrow$ when $t < -1$, instead of $f\searrow$?

Comment: It is decreasing on $(-\infty,-1)$ https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ahlksbozpg

Comment: My bad! I somehow messed up the directions, so I was viewing the function on at $t, t \to -\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

When $a=0$, the lower bound you obtained is attained when $z=c$. Otherwise, it is attained when $z=\frac{ia}{|a|}\sqrt{|c|^2-|a|^2}$. Therefore your lower bound is the best possible.

For upper bound, by triangle inequality we have
$$2|z|=|(z+a)+(z-a)|\le|z+a|+|z-a|=2|c|.$$
Therefore $|z|\le|c|$. When $a$ is nonzero, the upper bound is attained when $z=\frac{|c|}{|a|}a$. Otherwise, it is attained when $z=c$. Hence it is also the best possible.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $S:= \{z : |z + a| + |z - a| = 2|c|\}$. Suppose $z \in S$. Then $$2|z| \leq |z+a-(z-a)| \leq |z + a| + |z - a| = 2|c|, \ \ \ \ \text{i.e.,}  \ \ \   \text{max}_{z\in S} |z| = |c|$$

Here the maximum is attended at $z= |c|e^{-i\theta}$ where $\theta = \ \text{arg}\ \Big(\frac{|c|}{a}\Big)$.

If $z\in S$, then we see that the sum of the distances from the point $z$ to the given points $a$ and $-a$, is equal to to the constant $2|c|$. This means that $S$ represents an equation of ellipse with foci $\pm a$.

Moreover, if you take $a$ is real then then the equation of the ellipse using the rectangular coordinates is given by $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{c^2-a^2} = 1.$$ and its center is at the origin and its semi major and semi minor axis are equal to $c$ and $\sqrt{c^2-a^2}$ respectively.